# Выбрать элемент выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

у меня такая проблема, что я вывожу данные с помощью ajax jquery , с помощью события change. Данные появляются если выбрать определенный пункт выпадающего списка , но как сделать, чтобы один из options был выбран по умолчанию? чтобы данные появлялись с первым id-шником из value, который  станет по умолчанию.

```
<select class="changeTemplate form-control form-control-sm">
                    <option>Выберите шаблон</option>
                    <?php
                    $selected=true;
                    foreach ($templates as $templ) {
                        if($selected==true)
                        {
                            echo "<option class='selected' value='".$templ['_id']."' style='display:none;'>".$templ['title']."</option>";
                            $selected=false;
                        }
                        echo "<option value='".$templ['_id']."'>".$templ['title']."</option>";

                    }
                    ?>

                </select>
```

Как то сделать ,чтобы в id - запихнуть значение по умолчанию

```
  $(function () {
        $(".changeTemplate").change(function () {
            var id;
            id = $(".changeTemplate").val()
           $.ajax({
                url: urlToGetTemplates + '/' + id,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    loading = true;
                },
                complete: function () {
                    console.log('Complete');
                }, })
```

Comment: Если значения option заполнены просто установите одно из них атрибуту value оно и станет выбраным

Comment: не совсем понял вас

Comment: $('select.myClass').val('setValue')

Comment: Такой вариант не подойдет, для каждого юзера у меня разные данные в option

Comment: $('select.myClass option')[0].attr('selected' 'true');

Comment: $('#myId')[0].selectedIndex = 0